# Unrecoverable error when deleting fields

Tags: entities

I've copied a working site and trying to modify to make a new one. To do so I've deleted all nodes, vocabularies etc  but when deleting custom fields using field-delete in drush I'm getting the following error. Even from site UI I'm getting similar message. What could be the problem?

```
D:\xampp\htdocs\ido>drush field-delete field_posts --yes
Do you want to delete the field_posts field? (y/n): y
WD php: DatabaseSchemaObjectExistsException: Cannot rename field_data_field_posts to field_deleted_data_30: table field_deleted_data_30     [error]

already exists. in DatabaseSchema_mysql->renameTable() (line 307 of D:\xampp\htdocs\ido\includes\database\mysql\schema.inc).
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\ProgramData\Drush\includes\output.inc:37)                [warning]

bootstrap.inc:1212
DatabaseSchemaObjectExistsException: Cannot rename <em class="placeholder">field_data_field_posts</em> to <em class="placeholder">field_deleted_dat
a_30</em>: table <em class="placeholder">field_deleted_data_30</em> already exists. in DatabaseSchema_mysql->renameTable() (line 307 of D:\xampp\ht
docs\ido\includes\database\mysql\schema.inc).
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.      

                                                                [error]
```

Comment: You did delete the nodes/etc. through the UI and not straight out of the DB tables right?

Comment: I've not touched the database. Even before deleting the nodes I was seeing this error.

Comment: Phew :) Looks like the field purge is getting messed up. It's trying to create `field_deleted_data_30` which already exists. If the field system thinks it _doesn't_ exist it should be perfectly safe to remove the existing `field_deleted_data_30` table manually

Comment: Thanks .. but can I run drush field-delete on a site without removing nodes, vocabularies etc? Will it cause any sideaffects?

Comment: I've never used it so can't comment I'm afraid (I usually run `field_purge_batch()` manually). Take a copy of the database and do a dry run, that way you'll know for sure